# Creating a NSData object from an included file

Tags: macos, nsdata

I have an application which creates strict folder structures.

I also have some template files which should be placed in specific folders within that structure. My problem is that I'm not sure how to point to those files (which I've included in the project) so that I can create an NSData object from them. The plan was then to call the `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:` method of NSFileManager to save them to the folders.

How can I reference these included files? I tried using the NSData `dataWithContentsOfFile:` method and just setting the name of the file like so:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"Storyboard.template"];
```

but that does not appear to work.

Is there perhaps a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by, "I've included in the project", you mean you have these files in your bundle, then you should use the NSBundle method, pathForResource:ofType:, or one of its siblings to get the path.